# How to use AIDL in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-intent, aidl

I want to write a Xamarin-Application for Android (in C#) and to Interact with another application that is written in Java.

What's the best approach to do so?

Comment: you can create a binding wrapper for an Android library to call it from C# - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: So your recommended way would be to compile the osmand-api-project to a jar file and then invoke this jar-file from C#?

Comment: I only briefly glanced at it so don't take this as gospel - but generally if there is not a Xamarin library available but there is a native iOS/Android library, then creating a binding library is the best approach